# Object not retaining value on Timer Tick Event

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a timer event that calls something similar to the code below.  My problem is that intermittently, `myObject` variable doesn't retain value of  `bSuppress` or `sSuppress` from the previous execution, and I end up losing text. I can sometimes run my code 25 times without a problem. Then, out-of-the-blue it starts happening again, 1 out of every 4 times.  Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

```
Private myObject as New someClass
Private sOutput as string
Private cQueue As New Collection

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
       Dim sCmd as string

       sCmd=cQueue (1)
       sOutput &= myObject.getText(sCmd)
       cQueue.Remove(1)

end sub

Public Sub DoText(ByVal sText As String)
   'received from a socket connection on a separate thread
   cQueue.Add(sText)

End Sub

Public Class someClass

        Private sSuppress as String
        Private bSuppress as Boolean

        Public function getText(sText as String) as String

                'if we didn't end in a space during the last function call
                'than prepend the previous input string

                if bSuppress then
                    sText=sSuppress & sText
                end if

                If right(sText, 1)<>" " then
                     bSuppress=true
                     sSuppress=sText
                     exit function
                end if

             return sText

        end function
End Class
```

Comment: It is more likely that the string being sent isnt quite what you expected than a variable forgetting its state

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this code

```
If right(sText, 1)<>" " then
    bSuppress=true
    sSuppress=sText
    exit function
end if
```

one can tell that you're not guarantee value retention of `bSuppress` and `sSuppress`. When condition `right(sText, 1)<>" "` evaluates to `true`, your value will change.

Additionally, looking at your code I can mention the following

1. `Timer_Tick` runs on a different thread and there is no guarantee in order of execution there, especially if ticks are close
2. `cQueue.Add(sText)` and `cQueue(1)`... why not `cQueue(0)`? How you determine the index?
3. If you need a queue, why don't you use `Queue` object, and use `Collection` instead? Remember, today you should never use `Collection` and/or `ArrayList` - these are only exist for backwards compatibility.
4. May be you should tell us what are you trying to achieve and we can help you to refactor your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think, due to the Timer1_Tick() and DoText() operating on different threads, you need to use some sort of thread-safe mutual exclusion technique, such as a SyncLock. You don't want DoText() interrupting the statements in Timer1_Tick().

```
Private myObject As New someClass
Private sOutput As String
Private cQueue As New Collection
Private lock As New Object

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim sCmd As String

    SyncLock lock
        sCmd = cQueue(1)
        sOutput &= myObject.getText(sCmd)
        cQueue.Remove(1)
    End SyncLock

End Sub

Public Sub DoText(ByVal sText As String)
    'received from a socket connection on a separate thread

    SyncLock lock
        cQueue.Add(sText)
    End SyncLock

End Sub
```